# CPU Raytracer objects are warped

Tags: rust, graphics, 3d, raytracing

I'm currently reading the book Computer graphics from scratch and can't get the example from the first chapter about a [raytracer](https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/computer-graphics-from-scratch/02-basic-raytracing.html) quite right in my rust project.
I'm using the [image](https://crates.io/crates/image) crate to render the picture. I convert the coordinates from renderer (x and y, origin upper left corner) to to my viewport (origin in the middle, with z on 10).

```
fn canvas_to_viewport(x: u32, y: u32, scene: &Scene) -> Point {
    let x: f64 = x as f64 - (scene.width as f64 / 2.) ;
    let y: f64 = y as f64 - (scene.width as f64 / 2.) ;

    // x * viewport width / camera width
    // y * viewport height / camera height
    Point {
        x: x  * 1.,
        y: y  * 1.,
        z: 10.
    }
}
```

I then get the color of the pixel by my trace_ray function which looks for the closest intersection with a sphere with the helper function intersect_ray_sphere.

```
fn trace_ray(camera: Point, viewport: Point, t_min: f64, _t_max: f64, spheres: &Vec<Sphere>) -> Color {
    let mut closest_t = 1000.;
    let mut closest_sphere_color = Color (255,255,255);

    for sphere in spheres {
        let (t1, t2) = intersect_ray_sphere(camera, viewport, &sphere);
        if t1 > t_min && t1 < closest_t {
            closest_t = t1;
            closest_sphere_color = sphere.color;
        };
        if t2 > t_min && t2 < closest_t {
            closest_t = t2;
            closest_sphere_color = sphere.color;
        };
    }
       closest_sphere_color
}

fn intersect_ray_sphere(o: Point,  d: Point, sphere: &Sphere) -> (f64, f64) {
    let r = sphere.radius;

    let co = Point { 
        x: o.x - sphere.center.x, 
        y: o.y - sphere.center.y,
        z: o.z - sphere.center.z
    };

    let a = dot_product(&d, &d);
    let b = 2. * dot_product(&co, &d);
    let c = dot_product(&co, &co) - r*r;

    let discriminant = b*b - 4.*a*c;
    if discriminant < 0. {
        return (1000., 1000.);
    };

    let t1 = (-b + discriminant.sqrt()) / (2.*a);
    let t2 = (-b - discriminant.sqrt()) / (2.*a);
    return (t1, t2)
}
```

The spheres farther from the middle are warped as you can see here:

[image: picture]

I have played with pretty much all parameters but can't seem to figure it out. Every help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Simple stupid question but way at the top you have `let y: ... ` and then for `y` you use `scene.width` where really it should probably be `scene.height`.

Comment: Thanks I noticed that mistake already but unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing checks for `t1 < t_max` and `t2 < t_max`, though I suppose it doesn't matter much if your `t_max` is infinite.

Also, in case of a negative discriminant, you can actually return `inf` if you like, using [`f64::INFINITY`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#associatedconstant.INFINITY); using `1000` is likely the culprit for the warping effect you are seeing.